# Cannot add package description in ScalaDoc (Scala 3)

Tags: scala, scaladoc, scala-3

I cannot add a package description in ScalaDoc with Scala 3

```
/** package description */
package foo {
    /** some scaladoc comment */
    def method():A = ???
}
```

Then I generate the doc with sbt (1.5.3)

```
sbt> doc
```

I don't get the description of the package **itself** in the `index.html` file, but only the description of the `method` **inside** the package.

Comment: Maybe it is not possible anymore, as the scala 3 library do not use package comment, and `package object` is becoming deprecated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found the answer

> Scaladoc comments can go before fields, methods, classes, traits,
> objects. For now, **scaladoc doesn't support straightforward solution to
> document packages**. There is a dedicated github issue, where you can
> check the current status of the problem.

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/11284

Comment: I'm also interested in this issue, but the URL above is broken.

Comment: @MichelCharpentier, I updated the link.